# perl splicing array missing entries

Tags: perl

I was using splice to cut an array into parts. I am using perl. for the given code below:

```
my @array = (1..10021);
my @mypart;
my $slice_size = 500;
foreach (@array) {
    @mypart = splice(@array, 0, $slice_size);
    print STDOUT scalar(@mypart). "\n";
}
```

the outcome is as expected below:

```
% time ./splice_perf.pl
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
21
0.269u 0.039s 0:00.48 60.4% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

**Note that 21 is coming in the last.**

whereas if I change the array size to [my @array = (**1..10020**);]

the output missing the last digit, that is 20. the output looks like below:

```
% time ./splice_perf.pl
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
500
0.260u 0.048s 0:00.38 78.9% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

Please suggest if this is known or I am missing anything here.

Comment: Why are you using `foreach`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops):

> If any part of LIST is an array, `foreach` will get very confused if you add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with `splice`. So don't do that.

I suspect that's your problem. If you instead use a while loop, like so:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my @array = (1..10020);
my $slice_size = 500;
while (@array) {
    my @mypart = splice(@array, 0, $slice_size);
    say scalar(@mypart);
}
```

the last line printed out is `20` like you expect.

---

Notes:

- **Always** `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in perl scripts big enough to go in a file instead of a one liner. Maybe even then too.
- `print` and `say` print to standard output by default; no need for `print STDOUT ...;`.
- See use of [`say`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#say-FILEHANDLE-LIST) instead of a `print` with an explicit newline. If using the latter, use `print ..., "\n"` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Shawn, you made an important point. foreach was an mistake at my end. is there any performance impact if moving from print to say ? OR it is safe per your opinion. I have not used say ever. Thanks for correction !

Comment: `say` and `print` are basically the same thing, it's just `say` includes the trailing linefeed.

Comment: It's cleaner than having to explicitly add a newline, IMO.